# How to show all data from a mysql table in a Java Jtable with ArrayList?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, arraylist, jtable

I am trying to fill a JTable with all the data in the Mysql: City table.

I have a class called City, which has the methods and attributes of City, and this is its code:

```
package mainDashboard;

public class City{

private int id;
private String name;

 public City(){
}

public City(String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name= name;
}

    public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}

    @Override
public String toString() {
    return this.id+", "+this.name;
   }  
}
```

I have another class called CityModel in which I have all the necessary methods to Save Data, Update Data, Delete Data and Extract Data from the City table.

I have the problem to extract all the data from the city table and display them. For that reason, I'm going to show only the ListDataCity method from the Class CityModel:

```
 public ArrayList ListDataCity() {

 ArrayList DataCity= new ArrayList();

 City t_a = new City();

 int Id_Element = 0;

 sSQL = "SELECT * FROM city_data";

 try {
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

    while (rs.next()) {
        Id_Element = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
        t_a.setId(Id_Element);
        t_a.setName(rs.getString("city_name"));

        DataCity.add(t_a);
    }
    return DataCity;
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   return null;
  }
}
```

I show these data in a table of the ShowCityAll Class that is a JFrame.
When I press the ShowDataCity button, all data must be loaded into the table. This is my code:

```
     private void ShowDataCityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        Object CityObj[] = null; 

        modelTable.addRow(CityObj);

        ArrayList Results = new ArrayList(); 

        CityModel Db_ListCity;
        Db_ListCity= new CityModel();

        Results = Db_ListCity.ListDataCity();

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.size(); i++) 
        {
        City dataCityT = (City) Results.get(i);
modelTable.setValueAt(dataCityT.getId(), i, 0); modelTable.setValueAt(dataCityT.getName(), i, 1);
        }        
 }
```

This is the code of the Table element:

```
 DefaultTableModel modelTable;
 private void CreateModelShowCity(){
 try {
 modelTable= (new DefaultTableModel(
 null, new String [] {
 "ID","City Name"}){
 Class[] types = new Class [] {
 java.lang.String.class,
 java.lang.String.class
 };
 boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
 false,false
 };
 @Override
 public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
 return types [columnIndex];
 }
 @Override
 public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex){
 return canEdit [colIndex];
 }
 });
 jTableShowCity.setModel(modelTable);
 jTableShowCity.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
 jTableShowCity.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(150);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString()+"error2");
 }
 }
```

The city table in mysql has now six records. The problem is that only the last record is shown. I want to show all the records in the table, not just the last one.

The next error is also shown when I press the Button:

```
         Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:664)
at mainDashboard.ShowCityAll.ShowDataCityActionPerformed(ShowCityAll.java:1523)
at mainDashboard.ShowCityAll.access$100(ShowCityAll.java:18)
at mainDashboard.ShowCityAll$2.actionPerformed(ShowCityAll.java:223)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

can you help me solve this?
I'm starting in java, this is my first project.

Comment: Data for the TableModel should be stored in the TableModel. This means the ArrayList should be an instance variable in a custom TableModel. To create a custom TableModel for your City objects see [Row Table Model]() for a step by step example on how to do this.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: This question is too big, you should create something with a main that reproduces the problem. The mysql can be replaced with fixed data from a list. Alternatively, do some debugging for modelTable. Call getColumnCount() and getRowCount(), how does it compare with the values used at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

After looking briefly it looks like this might be your problem:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Id_Element = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
    t_a.setId(Id_Element);
    t_a.setName(rs.getString("city_name"));

    DataCity.add(t_a);
}
```

Try moving creating a new `City` into this portion of the code so you are not just reusing the same `object`.

Like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    City t_a = new City();
    Id_Element = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
    t_a.setId(Id_Element);
    t_a.setName(rs.getString("city_name"));

    DataCity.add(t_a);
}
```

Think about it this way, you only had a single `City` and were just changing its name and ID.  You have to actually *create* a new `City` to set those values to.

Also you should probably use `ArrayList<City>` instead of `ArrayList`, which is typically not good practice.

Another good practice would be using `PreparedStatement` over `Statement` as well in a real world scenario, because `Statement` is a security flaw and prone to SQL injection, so it might be wise to look into them.

EDIT:

I suspect you may have declared your `modelTable` without enough rows/columns which would be done with this:

```
DefaultTableModel modelTable = new DefaultTableModel(6, 2);
```

or for `JTable`

```
JTable modelTable = new JTable(6, 2);
```

This will create a `modelTable` with 6 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did this changes but it's still the same problem because now only the first record of the table City is shown. The table City has six records: 1. New Yor, 2. Miami, 3. Atlanta, 4. Orlando, 5. Philadelphia, 6. Ottawa. But now on the Jtable the only data shown is 1. New York.

Comment: @Marcos Schmell Can you show how you created the `modelTable`? I put an EDIT on what I suspect may be the problem, but you don't have that info posted here.

Comment: I have added the code that I use to create the modelTable